# Django - Feeding only part of Foreignkey in models

Tags: django, forms, filter, model, foreign-keys

i'm new to django and as a exercise I want to make "home expenses".
I've already did simple model and form :
(from models)

```
#models.py
#these are the type (groceries/clothes/etc. )
class TypWydatku(models.Model):
    typ_wydatku = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    data_wpisu=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

#these are the actual input with dates/prices/etc
class Wpisy(models.Model):
    data_zakupu=models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
    data_wpisu=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    typ_wydatku=models.ForeignKey(TypWydatku)
    kwota=models.FloatField('kwota')
    uwagi=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

But now I would like to add another model, which will describe expenses connected to my car more specific. So I add another TypWydatku - Moto with id=3

Next step is to create new model with extra fields (mileage/ fuel tanked):

```
#models.py 
(...)
class WpisyMoto(models.Model):
   wpis=models.ForeignKey(Wpisy)
   przebieg=models.IntegerField()
   uwagi=models.CharField(max_length=200)
   litry=models.FloatField()
   #and more
```

I have the sipmlest forms as one can have rigth now :

```
# forms.py
class TypWydatkuForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TypWydatku
        fields = '__all__'


class WpisyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Wpisy
        fields = '__all__'

class WpisyMotoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WpisyMoto
        fields = '__all__'
```

I would like to have choice field 'wpis' in the template, where i want to see onlythose which have 'typ_wydatku'=3. How should I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) for the ModelChoiceField field (which is the form field type Django will use to represent the ForeignKey field), this can be achieved by setting the form field's queryset attribute:

```
class WpisyMotoForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = WpisyMoto
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WpisyMotoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["wpis"].queryset = Wpisy.objects.filter(typ_wydatku__pk=3)
```

Comment: Works great ! double underscore is needed as typ_wydatku is also a foreign key to the TypWydatku model ?

Comment: Yep, a bit more details about it available at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships